# Function only clicks when provided static values, but will not click when identical values arrive from a function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

I'm using TensorflowJs and react to test gesture based interfaces. I've mapped an image cursor to my mobile phone and when i move my mobile phone across a camera feed, it moves the image element accordingly.

An object detection model runs in a react component like this:

```
const runCoco = async () => {
    const net = await cocossd.load();
    console.log("COCOSSD model loaded.");
    //  Loop and detect hands
    setInterval(() => {
      detect(net);
    }, 10);
  };

  useEffect(runCoco,[]);
```

```
  //public variables
  const webcamRef = useRef(null);
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const xScalar = 2.5;
  const yScalar = 1.7;
  const yShift = 389.203119516;
```

I move the cursor element over a large button in my program and when I want to click on an element i bring in a plastic bottle into frame (this was just a quick way to get testing). When the bottle is detected I call document.elementFromPoint(x,y) and dispatch a click event onto the element below the cursor at that time.

```
 const detect = async (net) => {
    // Check data is available
    if (
      typeof webcamRef.current !== "undefined" &&
      webcamRef.current !== null &&
      webcamRef.current.video.readyState === 4
    ) {
      // Get Video Properties
      const cursor = document.getElementById('cursor');  
      const video = webcamRef.current.video;
      const videoWidth = webcamRef.current.video.videoWidth;
      const videoHeight = webcamRef.current.video.videoHeight;

      // Set video width
      webcamRef.current.video.width = videoWidth;
      webcamRef.current.video.height = videoHeight;

      // Make Detections
      const obj = await net.detect(video);
      //console.log(obj);
        
      try
      {
        //all this manipulation below was just a good way I found to convert the bounding box outputs 
        //into comfortable larger x and y coordinates for the user to navigate with.
        x = (-1 * (((obj[0]['bbox'][0] + obj[0]['bbox'][2] ) / 2))) + 640;
        y = obj[0]['bbox'][1] - 200; ///200px higher than the top of the bounding box
        
        x = x * xScalar;
        y = (y * yScalar);
      
        if (obj[0]['class'] === "cell phone" && obj[0]['score'] > 0.8 )
        {
          prevX = x;
          prevY = y;
          cursor.style.transform = `translate(${ x }px, ${ y }px)`;
        }
        else if ( obj[0]['class'] === "bottle" )
        {
          
          console.log("");

          x = document.querySelector('#cursor').getBoundingClientRect().left;
          y = document.querySelector('#cursor').getBoundingClientRect().top;
          
          console.log( " Model Values: " + prevX + ", " + (prevY + yShift));
          console.log( " Cursor Values: " + x + " " + y );

          var ev = new MouseEvent('click', {
              'view': window,
              'bubbles': true,
              'cancelable': true,
              'screenX': x,
              'screenY': y
          });

          // x = 305.45550537109375;
          // y = 271.7203674316406;

          console.log( " Just before click: " + x + " " + y );
          var el = document.elementFromPoint( Math.trunc(x), Math.trunc(y) );
          console.log(" After click: " + x + " " + y)

          el.dispatchEvent(ev);
        }

      }
      catch (err)
      {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
      
  }
```

This is where the issue arises:
When I feed the literal values here, it works. the button is clicked and all is good.

```
x = 305.45550537109375;
y = 271.7203674316406;
```

```
var el = document.elementFromPoint( Math.trunc(x), Math.trunc(y) ); 
    el.dispatchEvent(ev);
```

But if I feed it this way:

```
x = document.querySelector('#cursor').getBoundingClientRect().left;
y = document.querySelector('#cursor').getBoundingClientRect().top;
```

No click is registered, the dispatched event does nothing.

Here is an image of some console outputs I tried to debug it with:
[image]

The values barely differ so I really can't figure out why it doesn't work.

[This is an image of a button and the cursor in the program, if it helps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceRlP.png)

Comment: Why do you log "After click" to the console when you have not yet fired the event?

Comment: You're right, its just an accident, I'll try that right away. thanks. EDIT: [it didn't change the results but thanks for the spot](https://imgur.com/a/FtMpaUK)

Comment: Can it be that you're clicking on the cursor itself? Can you add `el` into the logs?

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova https://i.imgur.com/y9DCJww.png Thank you, it was actually clicking on the cursor). I've styled it with 'pointer-events: none' and it all works now.

Comment: Awesome! Mystery solved :)

Comment: @Nadia Chibrikova, If the issue was resolved. It would be great, if you can post the answer for the benefit of community. Thanks!